# setTimeout location with internet explorer

Tags: javascript, php, settimeout, page-refresh

i try to reload the page after click on button

1- Click on button
2- Little message appear: "well done"
3- Refresh the page after 2 seconds

My code work fine except with internet explorer. Can you help me please

```
<form method="post" action="">
<button type="image" src="../../images/favoris.png"  class="ajouter"      value="ajouter" name="ajouter"></button> 
</form> 

<?php

if (isset($_POST['ajouter']) ) 
{
$sql = "INSERT INTO favoris (id, client) VALUES('','$pseudo')";
mysql_query($sql) or die('Erreur SQL ! '.$sql.'<br>'.mysql_error());

echo 'well done
<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.setTimeout("location=(\'\');",2000) 
</script>';
}
```

Thanks

Comment: try to use window.location=(\'\') instead of location=(\'\')

Comment: use `setTimeout(function() { /* your code here */ },2000) `